# SELECT only records with specific relations over 3 tables using MYSQL in m:n relations

Tags: mysql, select

I have 3 tables:

t_cards:

```
----------------------------
| card_id | customer_name |  
----------------------------
```

t_cardsxtags:

```
-------------------------
| ID | card_id | tag_id |  
-------------------------
```

t_tags:

```
---------------------
| tag_id | tag_name |  
---------------------
```

The relations between the cards and the tags is m:n, so a card can have multiple tags and a tag can belong to multiple cards.

Now my question is the following:
I want to select those records out of t_cards, which have certain tags(or more), e.g. tags with the tag_ids 33, 44 and 55.
So I want ALL those cards inlcuded in the selection:

- cards with exactly and only those tags
- cards with those tags which also have other additional tags

How do I do that using mysql?
**[edit]**
To be more specific: I want those selected, that have the tags 33,44 AND 55 (and maybe some additional tags)

Comment: http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html
http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/06/tagsystems-performance-tests.html

Comment: You said 3 tables, but your question only uses 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT * FROM t_cards c INNER JOIN t_cardsxtags ct ON c.card_id = ct.card_id WHERE ct.tag_id IN (33,44,55);
```

Comment: No, this selects all records with  tag 33, all with 44 and all with 55. I want to select those that have 33,44 AND 55 and maybe some more

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM
  t_cards t1
  INNER JOIN t_cardsxtags t2 ON t2.card_id=t1.card_id
WHERE t2.tag_id IN (33,44,55)
GROUP BY t1.card_id
HAVING (COUNT(t2.tag_id) == 3)
```

`3` is the number of tags

Comment: I guess I'm supposed to delete the line with "#3 is the number of tags", right?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't seem to work. The code also has some errors; selecting card_id with 33,44 or 55 doesn't make sense, but even after changing that it doesn't yield any results

Comment: I've made a mistake (typo) in the where conditions. It should be `tag_id`. sorry